# Problem while export to xls using spreadsheet gem in rails for Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spreadsheet

In my code

```
@format_text = @workbook.add_format(:bold =>false)
```

I get following error

```
undefined method `font' for {:bold =>false}:Hash in 
gems/spreadsheet-0.6.4/lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/workbook.rb:352
```

when i try to export data into the XLS  i am using following gems

```
spreadsheet --version 0.6.4
spreadsheet-excel --version 0.3.5.1
```

My problem is when i use same code with same gems it works fine on my local application but same gives error on my heroku server

Regards,

Salil

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass [Spreadsheet::Format](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/Spreadsheet/Format.html) instead of hash

```
format = Spreadsheet::Format.new
format.font = Spreadsheet::Font.new('Arial', :bold => true)
@workbook.add_format(format)
```

Comment: thanx a million man it works, now i am trying to set background.

Comment: do you know how to set background of the cell in xls?i want to set 'green' and 'black'

Comment: Spreadsheet::Format.new :pattern_fg_color => :red, :pattern => 1